# PHP, Python : Incremental Data Output

Tags: python, php

How to output the data incrementally from a ajax request when php executes a python script with variables? The below code output all the data on completion, my actual python script is large and can take over 10 minutes to complete. I like to see the printed status message embedded into the script. Or is there a is a better way then what I’m trying to attempt.

*Solution Found* I need to add 'sys.stdout.flush()' after each print request in python. Thank you to Sander Marechal!

```
$('#config_form').on('click', '.config-button', function () {
    var dataString =  'mystring1="test1"' +
                     '&mystring2="test2"' ;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",    
        url: "./php/pyhon_test.php",  
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        xhrFields: {
            onprogress: function(e) {
                console.log(e.target.responseText)
            }
        }
    });
    return false;   
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_write_close();
    
    $mystring1 = $_POST["mystring1"]; 
    $mystring2 = $_POST["mystring2"]; 

    $a = popen("/bin/python3.9 /var/www/html/cps/dops/python/python_script.py $mystring1 $mystring2 2>&1", "r"); 
    
    while($b = fgets($a, 2048)) { 
        echo $b; 
        ob_flush();flush(); 
    }
    pclose($a); 
    
    // Slow output progression to console.log
    $x = 1;
    while($x <= 5) {
        sleep(5);
        echo "pass-".$x."\r\n";
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        $x++;
    }   

    session_destroy();
?>
```

Python

```
import sys
import time

myvar1 = sys.argv[1]
myvar2 = sys.argv[2]

print(myvar1+"-a")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)

print(myvar2+"-b")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)

print(myvar1+"-c")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)

print(myvar2+"-d")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)

print(myvar1+"-e")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)

print(myvar2+"-f")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)
```

Console Log

```
console.log output loop 1.
true-contain
test1-a
test2-b
test1-c
test2-d
test1-e
test2-f
false

console.log output loop 2. 
pass-1
pass-2
pass-3
pass-4
pass-5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908112/run-python-file-and-read-output

Comment: I'm already doing the last two components of the link you provided.